# Contador de EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio, windows10, edittext

Trabajando con Android Studio, debo hacer un contador de caracteres de un EditText, este lo que hace es contar caracter por caracter cuando se le escriba. También contaria los espacios. Por ejemplo:

### *Contador de caracteres en Android*

```
                               33  <---- Contador de carcateres.
```

Comment: Además esto debe verse graficamente, el comentario encima del contador de caracteres

Comment: ¿Y qué has hecho hasta ahora? Pon tu código.

Comment: No he echo nada hasta ahora, lo único poner el edittext del comentario. No se hacerlo por eso lo pregunto

Comment: Pues, para lo que quieres hacer se usa la propiedad `length()` y con eso cuentas los caracteres :)

Comment: Material design tiene un componente el textfield ese tiene la opcion de contador de caracteres y limite de caractes cuantos.

Answer (score 0):

lo que quizás estés necesitando sea usar el evento del mismo editext llamado TextWatcher, esto te permite saber al momento que el usuario esta escribiendo en el mismo EditText.
Te dejo un ejem:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}});
```